# Alchemist Elixir mode and its company-mode backend

Tags: completion, company-mode

I'm using `alchemist.el` for editing Elixir code and have some difficulties to set it work properly with `company-mode`'s completion.
When I type (e.g): `List.|` I get `Company: An error occurred in auto-begin End of file during parsing`.
Alchemist's `README` on GitHub say `Alchemist enables a company-mode elixir backend by default if company-mode is installed.`
I guess that company backend somehow is not properly provided or I have some conflicts in configuration.
Does anyone have experience with this or have advice on how to debug this to see what is wrong or what is proper configuration?

Comment: You should file a bug in Alchemist.

Answer (score 4):

Please following the steps below

- Please update to the current Alchemist version 1.4.0
- Read the section about the requirements on the [README](https://github.com/tonini/alchemist.el#requirements)

If you then have still problems, please call me on the #elixir IRC channel, nickname is tonini

Thanks for the report and asking

Cheers